# ReadFileFromDisk kernelmode

Tags: c++, windows-kernel

I want to read a file from disk using a kernelmode driver. When I try to convert the `char` buffer to a `PCWSTR` it either returns `"/"` or `????????` or some other random characters. I took https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/help/891805/how-to-open-a-file-from-a-kernel-mode-device-driver-and-how-to-read-fr as reference.

I tried the following:

```
void ZwReadFromFile(PCWSTR FileName, char* outStr)
{
    UNICODE_STRING          UnicodeName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES       ObjectAttribute;
    HANDLE                  FileHandle;
    NTSTATUS                NTStatus;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK         IOStatusBlock;
    char                    FileBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    LARGE_INTEGER           ByteOffset;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&UnicodeName, FileName);
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttribute, &UnicodeName,
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
        NULL, NULL);


    NTStatus = ZwCreateFile(&FileHandle,
        GENERIC_READ,
        &ObjectAttribute, &IOStatusBlock,
        NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0,
        FILE_OPEN,
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
        NULL, 0);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(NTStatus)) 
    {
        ByteOffset.LowPart = ByteOffset.HighPart = 0;
        NTStatus = ZwReadFile(FileHandle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &IOStatusBlock,
        FileBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &ByteOffset, NULL);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(NTStatus)) 
        {
            FileBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
            DbgPrint("%s\n", FileBuffer);
            for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) 
            {
                outStr[i] = FileBuffer[i];
            }
        }
        ZwClose(FileHandle);
    }

}
```

DebugView using `DbgPrint("%s\n", buffer);` shows the correct output of my textfile, however when I try to convert it like:

```
char myStr[BUFFER_SIZE];
ZwReadFromFile(L"\\SystemRoot\\test.txt", myStr);
DbgPrint("%s\n", myStr);
```

It starts to act weird again. 
The Reason why I have to convert the char buffer to a PCWSTR is cause I am forced to use: `RtlInitUnicodeString(&myUnicode, myStr /*L"TEST"*/);`

Im struggling 3 days for it now, did research on google and stackoverflow but nothing really helped me to solve this Issue on my own. I appreciate any help I can get, sorry for my english im not a native speaker.

Comment: It reads bytes, not strings, so you'll have to zero-terminate yourself.  And you have to fret about the encoding of the text, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlmultibytetounicoden

Comment: There is no conversion to PCWSTR anywhere in this code.